# Laravel 5.7, Update <options> in a select drop-down with Vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm writing my first Laravel Vue component and I have this error in console.

> [Vue warn]: Computed property "options" was assigned to but it 
>   has no setter.

The code is about two select dropdowns, one with **continents** and one with **countries**. I want that when I update the **continent** the **countries** get updated.

I just miss to update the **options** of the second **select** with the updated values that I have in **this.countries**.

After the **continent** change the **this.countries** variable  get updated but the values of the options of the **country_id** select are not changing.
I've tried adding **computed** but I get this error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group continent_id">    
            <select name="continent_id" v-model="continent_selected" id="continent_id" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="false" title="Pick a continent" v-on:change="getAllCountries(continents)">
                <option v-if="continents.length>0" v-for="continent in continents" v-bind:value="continent.id">
                    {{ continent.name }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group country_id">    
            <select name="country_id" v-model="country_selected" id="country_id" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Pick a country">
                <option  v-for="(country, index) in countries" v-bind:value="country.id" >
                    {{ country.name }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
            this.loadData();
        },
        data() {
            return {
                continents: [],
                countries: [],
                continent_selected: '',
                country_selected: '',
            }
       },
       computed: {
           get: function () {
               return this.countries;
           },
           set: function (newValue) {
               this.countries = newValue; 
           }
       },
       methods: {
            loadData: function() {
                axios.get('/api/continents')
                .then((response) => {
                    // handle success
                    this.continents = response.data.data;
                    this.getAllCountries(this.continents);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    // always executed
                });
            },
            getAllCountries: function(continents) {
                console.log(this.continent_selected);
                console.log(continents);

                var j = 0;
                this.countries = [];

                for (var i = 0, len = continents.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if (!this.continent_selected){
                        for (var key in continents[i].active_countries) {
                            this.countries[j] = {id: continents[i].active_countries[key], name: key};
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("continent selected: "+ this.continent_selected);
                        for (var key in continents[i].active_countries) {
                            if (continents[i].id == this.continent_selected){
                                this.countries[j] = {id: continents[i].active_countries[key], name: key};
                                j++;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my issue that was mainly related to the computed set method of the variable **optionCountries**.

The dropdown was not updating because it use **Bootsrap Select**, so in order to show the new options it needs to be **refreshed**.

I've also figure out that I need to add a **timeout** to the refresh request.

This is the final code.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group continent_id">    
            <select name="continent_id" v-model="continent_selected" id="continent_id" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="false" title="Pick a continent" v-on:change="getAllCountries(continents)">
                <option v-if="continents.length>0" v-for="continent in continents" v-bind:value="continent.id">
                    {{ continent.name }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group country_id">    
            <select name="country_id" v-model="country_selected" id="country_id" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Pick a country">
                <option  v-for="(country, index) in optionCountries" v-bind:value="country.id" >
                    {{ country.name }}
                </option>  
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
            this.loadData();
        },
        data() {
            return {
                continents: [],  
                countries: [],
                continent_selected: '',
                country_selected: '',
            }
       },
       computed: {
           optionCountries:{   
               get: function () {
                    return this.countries;
                },
                set: function (newValue) {
                    this.countries = newValue;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                       jQuery('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
                    }, 500);
                }
            } 
        },

       methods: {
            loadData: function() {  
                axios.get('/api/continents')
                .then((response) => {
                    // handle success
                    this.continents = response.data.data;
                    this.getAllCountries(this.continents);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    // always executed
                });
            },
            getAllCountries: function(continents) {                
                var j = 0;
                this.countries = [];

                for (var i = 0, len = continents.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if (!this.continent_selected){
                        for (var key in continents[i].active_countries) {
                            this.countries[j] = {id: continents[i].active_countries[key], name: key};
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        for (var key in continents[i].active_countries) {
                            if (continents[i].id == this.continent_selected){
                                this.countries[j] = {id: continents[i].active_countries[key], name: key};
                                j++;
                            }
                        }
                        this.optionCountries = this.countries;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line you are setting the value of options attribute:

```
this.options = this.options;
```

, but, this property is computed:

```
computed: {
    options: function(event) {
        return this.countries
    }
},
```

In this case you can:

1. create a computed setter: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

   computed: {
   options: {
   get: function () {
   return this.countries;
   },
   set: function (newValue) {
   this.countries = newValue;
   }
   }
   },
2. Set the value directly:

   this.countries = this.options;

Comment: I've tried both, the error disappear but to one works..
The second dropdown doesn't get updated yet.

Comment: I vote your question up because it contribute to unstuck my problem bringing me on the way to find the solution. Thank your for the time you spent for my question!